# math.pi not working as expected in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to draw an oscillating rectangle in pygame.

When I use

```
particle.pos[0] = 100 * math.sin(188.5 * t) + screen_width / 2
```

it works as I expect it to, but when I use

```
omega = 2*math.pi*fps
particle.pos[0] = 100 * math.sin(omega * t) + screen_width / 2
```

the rectangle is drawn, but doesn't move. I've confirmed that omega is about 188.5 and that both omega and 188.5 are floats. The only thing I can think of is that math.pi is somehow causing the problem, but I don't know why.

edit:
The whole thing

```
import sys
import math
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

fps = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen_width, screen_height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))


class Particle:
    """Particle"""
    def __init__(self, size, pos, particlecolor):
        self.size = size
        self.pos = pos
        self.particlecolor = particlecolor

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [self.pos, self.size])

particle = Particle([10, 10], [screen_width * .25, screen_height * .5], GREEN)

t = 0
omega = 2*math.pi*fps

while True:
    t += 1
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    particle.pos[0] = 100 * math.sin(omega * t) + screen_width / 2
    # particle.pos[0] = 100 * math.sin(188.5 * t) + screen_width / 2

    particle.draw()

    pygame.display.flip()
fpsClock.tick(fps)
```

Comment: [More code please](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @skrx added code

Comment: Considering that when `t` is 0, the result is 320, and `t` at 100 results in `319.9999999997962`, I'm not surprised that it moves very little when you go up by 1 at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use multiples of 2*math.pi radians as your angle (that would be 360° (a full circle)) so you get almost the same result from the expression `100 * math.sin(omega * t) + screen_width / 2`.

```
print 100 * math.sin(omega * t) + screen_width / 2
```

Output:

```
319.99999999999784
319.9999999999957
319.99999999998784
319.99999999999136
319.9999999999949
319.99999999997567
319.99999999997925
```

Try `omega = 0.1` radians to get a nice result.